# What color is this round plate?

Tags: part-identification, colour

I got a bunch of used LEGO bricks from a friend. The bricks were made sometime between 2002 and 2016 when I was not playing with LEGO. I don’t know what set it came from and I can’t figure out what color it is. The square plate is “Dark Turquoise” based on the brick separator being available in that color. This is a darker version of “Dark Turquoise”.

Edited: Thanks for the help. This is a heavily but uniformly discolored blue brick. A chip taken out of it reveals a color of plastic much closer to blue under the surface.

[image]

Additional photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As @SanderDeDycker has mentioned try taking another picture with few more pieces in (known) shades of blue and green. Perhaps also add Red and Yellow for contrast. And see if you can take a picture with light source being on the top.

Comment: I hav tried several times to make a link into a picture and keep coming up short. I took a picture with more blue bricks of various colors. I thought there was a color I was missing. Based on this conversation and my inability to find any other pieces in this color, it appears Lego let something miss-colored into the wild.

Comment: I'd say this is Blue colored element that has yellowed over time. You can see some plastic has broken of round plate revealing the inside plastic and it appears to be close to usual Blue color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part is called [Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole (x Shape)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4032b#T=C&C=7) and is known to exist in sets in 13 colors (quite more are for sale though). Based on this list and the [color photos of all known blue hues](https://brickset.com/colours/family-Blue), I'd guess it is a [blue](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4032b&colorID=7&in=A) (Bricklink, with the official LEGO palette "23 Bright Blue") one - maybe with quite extreme color variation caused by molding errors or white balance during photography: the dark turquoise is a lot darker here as over at Brickset as well. The release years of the sets it was available in (2005-2010) do indeed match the given timeframe.

Is the background a plain white sheet of paper? Calibrating the white balance of the image to that known value might bring the colors of the photo closer to reality.

Can you say for sure that it came from an official set and not from a custom order or Pick-a-Brick batch? That would help reduce the list of possible colors as well.

Comment: Yes it is a white piece of paper. I got the brick in a large plastic tub of many bricks. I can say nothing about where it came from. Can one order custom colors of bricks from Lego?

Comment: "Custom" as in "colors that normally do exist but were not released with that piece design": yes, but not "custom" as in "please mix this RGB/CYMK/Pantone/RAL/... color for me". See https://www.lego.com/en-de/pick-and-build/pick-a-brick and https://brickarchitect.com/lugbulk/ for two very different ways of doing this.

Comment: Keeping in mind Blue version of this round plate type was available between 2006 and 2010 (according to Bricklink) this could also be heavily "yellowed" Blue colored piece. Which makes it appear more green-ish.

Comment: I don’t think this is a blue piece nor that it is “yellowed”. For the last 5 years it has been floating around my lego bin sandwiched between two other round plates. If it were yellowed I would expect the color change to be uneven.

Comment: @TroyCongdon : if you have a confirmed blue piece that you can add to the picture, maybe that'll help.

Comment: A chip was removed from the underside of the brick. It shows a different, bluer color under the surface. This is a discolored blue brick. Thanks to all who contributed.